¿Qué quiere decir “andas muy película” en Colombia?
Una amiga colombiana usó esa frase y desconozco su significado

Andas muy película


The phrase de película is used to mean unusual but more context would help us here.

Tal vez dijo "empeliculado" o "de película"?. Nunca usamos "muy película".

O tal vez "andas muy peliculero" es el sentido de fantasioso.

La expresión “Andas muy película” se usa para decir que alguien está actuando de forma exagerada o dramática, como si estuviera en una película.
Es una forma coloquial y divertida de señalar que alguien está siendo un poco teatral en su comportamiento.
